# How to find the maximum value of $x$ for the given series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

If it is given that $$\displaystyle \frac{1}{(20-x)(40-x)}+\displaystyle \frac{1}{(40-x)(60-x)}+....+\displaystyle \frac{1}{(180-x)(200-x)}= \frac{1}{256}$$ then how to find the maximum value of $x$ ? I tried solving it with $V_n$ method but it is getting more tedious.

Comment: $$40-x-(20-x)=?$$

Comment: Use a telescope to see the solution maybe? P.S.The difference between the product terms is 20.

Comment: $\frac{1}{(20-x)(40-x)}=\frac{1}{20 (x-40)}-\frac{1}{20 (x-20)}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{(40-x)-(20-x)}{(20-x)(40-x)}+\frac{(60-x)-(40-x)}{(40-x)(60-x)}+...+ \frac{(200-x)-(180-x)}{(180-x)(200-x)}=\frac{20}{256}\\\implies\frac1{20-x}-\frac1{40-x}+ \frac1{40-x}-\frac1{60-x}+...+\frac1{180-x}-\frac1{200-x}=\frac{20}{256}\\\implies\frac1{20-x}-\frac1{200-x}=\frac{20}{256}\\\implies\frac{200-x-20+x}{(20-x)(200-x)}=\frac{20}{256}\\\implies\frac{180}{(20-x)(200-x)}=\frac{20}{256}\\\implies\frac9{(20-x)(200-x)}=\frac1{256}\implies x=8,212$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the first two fractions only. If we adjust the denominators and add them together, we get:
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac{(60-x)}{(20-x)(40-x)(60-x)}+\frac{(20-x)}{(20-x)(40-x)(60-x)} \\
&=\frac{(80-2x)}{(20-x)(40-x)(60-x)}=\frac{2}{(20-x)(60-x)}
\end{align}
$$
When we telescope in the next fraction, we get:
$$\frac{3}{(20-x)(80-x)}$$
And this pattern continues. The sum of the nine fractions is therefore:
$$\frac{9}{(20-x)(200-x)} = \frac{1}{256}$$
I'll leave solving for $x$ to you, though it seems another answer has appeared that may include that.